# How to Preserve White Space and line breaks in Django?

Tags: css, django, forms, styling

I am making a project where I want to display a user's code. I am using Django's forms. But when I post that form, the form doesn't preserve the white space and the line breaks.

Can you please help me?

```py
# this is my form

class VigenereCipherDiscussForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = VigenereCipherDiscuss
        fields = ['text', 'share']

        widgets = {
            "text": forms.Textarea(attrs={"class":"form-control", "rows":4}),
            "share": forms.Textarea(attrs={"class":"form-control", "rows":5, "placeholder": "Put in your cipher text or code in here to share with others"})
        }

# (stackoverflow preserves the line breaks, the "class Meta" is indented nicely)
```

If i have this code:

```py
x = 2
if x == 2:
    return "2"
else:
    return None

# I want this code to be outputted in the form the way it is right now!
```

But django gives me

x=2 if x==2: return "2" else return None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [linebreak](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks)

change your code to:

```
x=2\nif x==2:\nreturn "2"\nelse:\nreturn None
```

and in template:

```
{{ value|linebreaks }}
```

Comment: I tried using linebreaks, but it doesn't work that much! But for every sentence, I don't want to add "\n"

Answer (score 1):

you can use tinymce to create a user's code.it will save it in html.
and in your .html add this:`{{ value|linebreaks|safe }}`
the tinymce Like this：[image]

Comment: Ok, I will try that out and let you know if that works! Thank you.